npm install sqlite3 --save does not work on both powershell and git bash
I installed knex to connect to mysql database from my Nextjs application.
But Knex returned me this error:

Knex: run
$ npm install sqlite3 --save
Cannot find module 'sqlite3'
Require stack:

C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Programming\chessgames\chessgames-app\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js
C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Programming\chessgames\chessgames-app\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\index.js
C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Programming\chessgames\chessgames-app\node_modules\knex\lib\knex-builder\internal\config-resolver.js
C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Programming\chessgames\chessgames-app\node_modules\knex\lib\knex-builder\Knex.js
C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Programming\chessgames\chessgames-app\node_modules\knex\lib\index.js


So I did npm install sqlite3 --save but it does not work on both Powershell and git bash
In Powershell , I get this error:
PS C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Programming\chessgames\chessgames-app> npm install sqlite3
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Programming\chessgames\chessgames-app\node_modules\sqlite3    
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command powershell -c prebuild-install -r napi || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! At line:1 char:26
npm ERR! + prebuild-install -r napi || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! +                          ~~
npm ERR! The token '||' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
npm ERR!     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException       
npm ERR!     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-05-12T19_45_44_730Z-debug-0.log       
PS C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Programming\chessgames\chessgames-app>

in git bash, I get this error
$ npm install sqlite3 --save
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm/node: line 8: 
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: No such file or directory

It does not really matter in which environment the command needs to work, I just want to make it work somehow. How can I fix this issue?

Ok, prebuild-install -r napi || node-gyp rebuild. || is not supported in Powershell. Solution to this problem was to install Powershell7 and do command npm config set script-shell pwsh . After that I could install that package in my vsc powershell terminal
